# Jenkins:java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist:/src/***/Chrome_Drivers/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe

Tags: selenium, jenkins

Exception while taking screenshot Cannot invoke method getScreenshotAs() on null object
Tests run: 2, Failures: 2, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.907 sec <<< FAILURE! -

java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist:/src/***/Chrome_Drivers/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe

While running the selenium jobs in Jenkins, how should we specify the chrome driver path?
I am trying to run the code in windows and the same code is running fine in my local however when I try to run the same code with Jenkins(code in bitbucket) it does not find the path.
I tried adding bitbucket URL in the System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "https://bitbucket.org/***/***/src/***/config/chromedriver.exe");

but nothing works.
Please help.

Comment: you can use WebDriverManager, so you don't required to pass the chromedriver path.

Comment: https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager

Comment: Thanks, @Dhru'soni that was really helpful, that error is resolved now however now I get error as :  org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: 
unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary,Can you please help here?

Comment: Which system you are using ?

Comment: I am trying to run through Jenkins on Linux machine

Comment: I get same error while running though Jenkins on windows as well.